# How to POST with missing authenticity_token in rspec rails request test?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, csrf, authenticity-token

I'm simulating a request coming from an external service, which will not have an authenticity token. I want the test to fail if `skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token` is missing.

How do I do this from an Rspec request spec?

Currently I'm using `post` as below, but it is happily accepted.

```
post endpoint, my_json_string, {'CONTENT_TYPE' => "application/json"}
```

Answer (score 60, accepted):

CSRF protection [disabled in test environment](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v5.0.0.1/actionpack/lib/action_controller/metal/request_forgery_protection.rb#L72). Try to enable it use:

```
before do
  ActionController::Base.allow_forgery_protection = true
end

after do
  ActionController::Base.allow_forgery_protection = false
end
```

Comment: As of Rails 4.2.5.1 and Rspec 3.4, this technique works fine. I suspect this is the proper way to implement the solution.

Comment: For tests of CSRF protection, one may need [the `raise_error` matcher](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/v/3-5/docs/built-in-matchers/raise-error-matcher): `expect { post endpoint, my_json_string }.to raise_error(ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken)`. I thought I was supposed to check the return code of response.

Comment: Nice solution even for Rails 5 (API) nowadays.

Comment: I think, that for `request` specs this should be enabled by default, so I put in `spec_helper.rb` this: ` config.before(:each, type: :request) do
    ActionController::Base.allow_forgery_protection = true
  end`  and tag correctly request specs

Answer (score 2):

Disabling CSRF protection didn't work for me. So I created this module which uses the response body to retrieve the authenticity token:

https://gist.github.com/Rodrigora/440220a2e24bd42b7b0c

Then, I can test put/post requests without disabling forgery protection:

```
before do
  @token = login(create(:user, password: 'password'))
end

it 'tests model creation' do
   expect {
     post_with_token 'path/to/model', model_params, @token
   }.to change(Model, :count).by(1)
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Trying to change `ActionController::Base.allow_forgery_protection` in a `before` or a `config.around(:each` didn't work for me in Rails 6, because the controller already has cached the value of `allow_forgery_protection` before the rspec callback runs.

The solution which worked was:

```
allow_any_instance_of(ActionController::Base).to receive(:protect_against_forgery?).and_return(true)
```

which can be found [here](https://blog.tomoyukikashiro.me/post/test-csrf-in-feature-test-using-capybara).